# AvaloniaUI - ExtendClientAreaToDecorationsHint and Panel

Tags: c#, avaloniaui

I will improve my skill to developp in C#. I used to developp in C++ and Python.
I already train my self with consol application and I found the implementation of the POO paradigme very strong.

So I will try to produce UI like I can do in C++ and Python.
I follow this tutoriel : http://avaloniaui.net/docs/advanced-tutorial/
But I haven't the expected result like in the chapter : create-a-modern-window.
My windows buttons close, minimize and maximize are behind the panel. So It's hard to see this buttons. [voir image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AGet.png)

Of course, if I had Margin on the panel or if I remove panel, buttons is correctly visible.

It seems to me logic, that if I put a panel in front of something, it gives this result.
But the tutorial give nothing more and I check on the github : https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia.MusicStore/tree/master/Avalonia.MusicStore and I found no difference with my code.

So do you have an idear of the problem or how to solves them ?

I work on Windows 10 with Avalovia 0.10.0.

My main window :

```xml
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="using:Avalonia.MusicStore.ViewModels"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
        x:Class="Avalonia.MusicStore.Views.MainWindow"
        Icon="/Assets/avalonia-logo.ico"
        Title="Avalonia.MusicStore"
        
        TransparencyLevelHint="AcrylicBlur"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Background="Transparent"
        ExtendClientAreaToDecorationsHint="True">

    <Design.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Design.DataContext>

    <Panel>
        <ExperimentalAcrylicBorder IsHitTestVisible="False">
            <ExperimentalAcrylicBorder.Material>
                <ExperimentalAcrylicMaterial
                    BackgroundSource="Digger"
                    TintColor="Black"
                    TintOpacity="1"
                    MaterialOpacity="0.65" />
            </ExperimentalAcrylicBorder.Material>
        </ExperimentalAcrylicBorder>
        <Panel Margin="40">
            <Button Content="Buy Music" Command="{Binding BuyMusicCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <PathIcon Data="{StaticResource store_microsoft_regular}"/>
            </Button>
        </Panel>
        
    </Panel>
</Window>
```

And my App.axaml

```xml
Application xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="using:Avalonia.MusicStore"
             x:Class="Avalonia.MusicStore.App">
    <Application.DataTemplates>
        <local:ViewLocator/>
    </Application.DataTemplates>

    <Application.Styles>
        <FluentTheme Mode="Dark"/>
        <StyleInclude Source="avares://Avalonia.MusicStore/Icons.axaml"/>
    </Application.Styles>
</Application>
```

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there was a minor bug in 0.10 release.

Please set on your Window the following property:

`ExtendClientAreaChromeHints="PreferSystemChrome"`

Comment: Thank you ! It works very well :)

I like the avalonia mecanic and ui but the documentations are hard to find.